# Yii2 - check if the user is logged in view

Tags: yii, yii2

I am trying to check is the user logged inside my view file, but I keep getting this error:

```
Call to undefined method Yii::app()
```

I tried adding **$** before **app** but the error is still there (this time it is **Undefined variable: app**). Is it possible to this is view?

This is the code I use the check if the user is logged:

```
<?php
        if(Yii::app()->isGuest)
            echo 'User is not logged!';
    ?>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In Yii2 the correct syntax is

```
Yii::$app->user->getIsGuest();
```

or

```
Yii::$app->user->isGuest;
```

Look at the documentation for more details: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

In yii2 you have to define the `app()` with `$` sign as `$app()`.

```
<?php
       if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        echo 'User is not logged!';
       }
?>
```