# Yii2 check if user is loggedin in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a controller action that i would like to check if user is a guest in yii2 but the code fails even if the user is a guest this is what i have tried

```
class CustomerController extends Controller
 {

   public function beforeAction($action)
    {
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl("site/login"));
    }


   public function actionDashboard(){
    //do dashboard stuff
   }

  }
```

I have also tried using accessControl filters but they still fail
This is the access control filter instance in a Frontend Controller

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'controllers' => ['customer'],
                    'actions' => ['dashboard'],
                    'allow' => true,
                    'users' => ['?'],
                ],

            ], // rules

        ], // access


    ]; // return

} // behaviors
```

Then on my customer controller i just extend Frontend Controlller but even with this approach it fails

BY DOING IT THIS WAY

```
public function actionDashboard(){
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        return $this->redirect(Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl("site/login"));
    }else{

      //perform dashboard stuff

    }

}
```

This works but the problem is that by following the last approach there is alot of code duplication in the other actions which doesnt seem right even though it works

What is wrong with the latter approaches which seem better

I have checked on [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30898214/yii2-check-if-the-user-is-logged-in-view) and also [This second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25998122/yii2-global-filter-behavior-to-force-user-to-authenticate-first) and implementend them but none works

WHAT COULD BE WRONG.

```
AM using Yii2 improved advanced template
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the [guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) at all? This is explained there in details...

Add this method in the controller that should be hidden from guests.

```
public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        'access' => [
            'class' => \yii\filters\AccessControl::className(),
            'rules' => [
                [
                    'allow' => true,
                    'roles' => ['@'],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ];
}
```

That's it.

Every action in controller with this behavior is accessible only by signed users. Guests are automatically redirected to the login page (default `site/login`).